# Is e-whoring legal?

Tags: france, social-media

I have created a fake female identity on Internet, I have an Instagram and a Snapchat, and I'm selling "nudes", photos of the person (photos that I stole from a website). I already made around 400$ in a week, I know it is unethical, but is it legal?

Edit: I'm in France

Comment: Well, its copyright infringement at the very least...

Comment: @Moo you actually can't copyright a face, and if the terms of service of the "website" they are using deems uploaded photos as creative commons there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Since there is money changing hands this would probably be considered fraud.

Comment: @User37849012643 the photos are going to be under copyright, face or not.

Comment: Yes indeed, the images that I'm using are copyrighted by the person. I think I will stop this activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is illegal in this case. [Article 313-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070719&idArticle=LEGIARTI000006418191) of the Criminal Code

> Fraudulent obtaining is the act of deceiving a natural or legal person by the use of a false name or a fictitious
>   capacity, by the abuse of a genuine capacity, or by means of unlawful manoeuvres, thereby to lead such a person, to his
>   prejudice or to the prejudice of a third party, to transfer funds, valuables or any property, to provide a service or to
>   consent to an act incurring or discharging an obligation.
>
> Fraudulent obtaining is punished by five years' imprisonment and a fine of €375,000

In French:

> L'escroquerie est le fait, soit par l'usage d'un faux nom ou d'une fausse qualité, soit par l'abus d'une qualité vraie, soit par l'emploi de manoeuvres frauduleuses, de tromper une personne physique ou morale et de la déterminer ainsi, à son préjudice ou au préjudice d'un tiers, à remettre des fonds, des valeurs ou un bien quelconque, à fournir un service ou à consentir un acte opérant obligation ou décharge.
>
> L'escroquerie est punie de cinq ans d'emprisonnement et de 375 000 euros d'amende.